# how to send Extent report when the name of the report changes

Tags: jenkins

i have jenkins with HTML Publisher Plugin and i can send reports while they are at the same name each build, but i want option to send reports when the name of the reports are generated each day with the name of the reports, is there way to do these?
EX - Htmal_report_15.04.2019
attach [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl6XE.jpg) how it looks right now

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYSC8.jpg)

Comment: show how you are using you publisher now so i can modify it for you.

Comment: @mbn217 [pictures](https://i.imgur.com/YvqgvLr.jpg)
it taking the code from Git

Comment: I cant see it, can you paste it within your post?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/YvqgvLr.jpg
now?

Comment: I still cant see it but this is an example of using it to take all .html files    publishHTML([allowMissing: false, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false, keepAll: false, reportDir: 'target/', reportFiles: '.*.html', reportName: 'HTML Report', reportTitles: ''])

Comment: I used .* to take all html format file let me know if it works

Comment: @mbn217 can you paste image with the right settings?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have :

```
always {

    echo 'I have finished'
    archiveArtifacts 'PTs.html'
    publishHTML (target: [
              allowMissing: false,
              alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
              keepAll: true,
              reportDir: 'target/surefire-reports/',
              reportFiles: 'index.html',
              reportName: "TestNG Report"
            ])
    publishHTML([allowMissing: false, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false, keepAll: false, reportDir: '.', reportFiles: 'PTs.html', reportName: 'ExtentReport', reportTitles: ''])
    emailext attachLog: true, attachmentsPattern: '*.html', body: 'Smoke Test.\n\nPlease see attachment for Report and build Logs', subject: 'DO NOT REPLY: JENKINS Build Server Notification [${BUILD_STATUS}]${JOB_NAME} Build #${BUILD_NUMBER}', to: 'addemailhere'
    //deleteDir()
}
```

you will need to use *.html for all html file

Use like this :
[image: email publisher]

Comment: this is a declarative pipeline job , are you using a maven job?

Comment: yes i am, or freeStyle, so i guess i can't use it, any solution to freestyle or maven project?

Comment: i edited my post with a screen shot , you need to use *.html to get any html regradless of the name

Comment: the screenshot is still under the pipeline, correct? like all the solution

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to to include report based on latest timestamp only. For me extent report is getting generated with run time timestapmp in format `"AutomationTestRunReport_" + timeStamp + ".html"` so how to add only the latest run test result as an attachment, using *.html will includes all .html reports and currently it's not useful for me